# What happens when I close curl? Could not closing cause a 500: internal server error?

Tags: php, curl

I sometimes get an out of memory error from some of my curls to a REST web service.

```
{
"StatusCode": 500,
"Title": "Internal Server Error",
"Message": "Out of memory"
}
```

The problem is always fixed by contacting the owner of the server I am connecting to via curl, who performs a reboot of some sort.

I know that not all of my scripts close the curl when they are done.

I'm just wondering if not closing a curl is contributing to that error or if closing the curl session only affects the resources on my server.

---

I'm sure someone will ask why I don't just close the curl and I probably should. But I'm wondering if that will actually fix the problem or not as there are sometimes weeks or months between those errors.

Comment: As I understand this JSON is being returned from remote server, so the problem is somewhere on that server.

Comment: `curl` runs on your server. The `500` error message is generated by the script that runs on the remote server. It is not related in any way to `curl`. `curl` is just an HTTP client. You will get the same error if you do your requests using another HTTP client (command line `curl`, `wget` or a regular browser).

Comment: ok, that's what I was afraid of. Although I'm glad I'm not causing the problem, it would be easier if I could be the one to fix it.

Comment: @axiac Yeah, that's what I thought. But since I am not quite sure how all of this works, I was wondering if not closing the curl on my server could be using up memory on the other server. That is, it would be keeping something in memory until I would release it.

Comment: It depends on your setup. If you did change the default settings in a way that PHP never ends the scripts executed or if it takes a long time (let's say 48 hours), then it could affect it. Actually we know just one thing: **The memory used by your scripts is constantly increasing.** You should get a list of running processes and compare it from time to time to see what's exactly going on. After that you should post the code of the problematic scripts here, so we can analyze the code and find the issue.

Comment: Not sure, if I understood you. Are you running any code on the server? If not, then it's of course not your problem. You can't DOS a web server that way lol.

Comment: @ArminŠupuk Nope, I'm just sending a request to the other server and then receive a json response. The only code I'm running is on my server.

Comment: @Andri It looks like the person which is running the server isn't very experienced, maybe it would help if you give him some hints, so he could solve the problem. An easy (and wrong) way to solve this issue would be to use some sort of process manager to automatically restart the process. It's easy to setup and would at least increase the uptime.